# How to have docker compose init a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that creates a starts SQL Server. This is working fine. I can connect to the database and see the master database.

What I am trying to do is create a new database, and add a table and some data to that table.  I have been unable to find an example of doing this using SQL Server. All the examples I have seen are either using PostgreSQL or Mysql.

I have tried to adapt this example [Docker Compose MySQL Multiple Database](https://onexlab-io.medium.com/docker-compose-mysql-multiple-database-fe640938e06b)

I have created an init directory with a file called 01.sql and the only thing in it is

```
CREATE DATABASE `test`;
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
services:
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        ports:
            - 1433:1433
        volumes:             
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "password123!"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

When I run docker-compose up

I'm not seeing anything in the logs that implies it's even trying to load this file.  When I check the database I do not see any new database either.

I am at a loss to understand why this isn't working for SQL Server but the tutorial implies that it works for MySql. Is there a different command for SQL Server?

Comment: The way MySQL does it, by running scripts in the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory, is MySQL specific. The MSSQL docs for the Docker image has a suggestion on how to initialize a database in the "How to use this image" section. At first glance it seems to require more work than the MySQL approach. https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Comment: Microsoft's own SQL Server-in-a-container documentation points to the [mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) demo repo. You can pretty much ignore most of their container setup - the interesting part is to use `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to run your own `entrypoint.sh` script that starts the SQL Server service and then sits in a retry loop invoking `sqlcmd` to connect and import data from a `setup.sql` script.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes I noticed the ENTRYPOINT  and CMD in a couple of other scripts i ran across.   This will take more research thanks for the tip

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After quite a bit of Googling and combining four or five very old tutorials, I got this working. Ensuring that you are using Linux line endings is critical with these scripts.

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    build: ./Db
    ports:
        - 1433:1433
```

Db/DockerFile

```
# Choose ubuntu version
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU13-ubuntu-20.04

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy initialization scripts
COPY . /usr/src/app
             
# Set environment variables, not have to write them with the docker run command
# Note: make sure that your password matches what is in the run-initialization script 
ENV SA_PASSWORD password123!
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_PID Express

# Expose port 1433 in case accessing from other container
# Expose port externally from docker-compose.yml
EXPOSE 1433

# Run Microsoft SQL Server and initialization script (at the same time)
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

Db/entrypoint.sh

```
# Run Microsoft SQl Server and initialization script (at the same time)
/usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Db/run-initialization.sh

```
# Wait to be sure that SQL Server came up
sleep 90s

# Run the setup script to create the DB and the schema in the DB
# Note: make sure that your password matches what is in the Dockerfile
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P password123! -d master -i create-database.sql
```

Db/create-database.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE [product-db]
GO

USE [product-db];
GO

CREATE TABLE product (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    Description TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
GO

INSERT INTO [product] (Name, Description)
VALUES 
('T-Shirt Blue', 'Its blue'),
('T-Shirt Black', 'Its black'); 
GO
```

Tip: If you change any of the scripts after running it the first time you need to do a `docker-compose up --build` to ensure that the container is built again or it will just be using your old scripts.

Connect:

```
host:  127.0.0.1
Username: SA
Password:  password123!
```

Comment: Does it work for you without inserting a context in the Docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 17):

Here is a docker-compose.yml sample with SQL server Microsoft image (without build) that does not rely on delay (I am not sure if it is a reliable way to wait for the SQL Server instance to start).

This approach is using additional setup container that executes your initialization SQL scripts as soon as main SQL Server container initializes itself.

I used the same `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` image as it contains SQL Server tools in it, but feel free to use any image you like with SQL Server tools installed in it.

```
version: '3.8'


volumes:
  sqlserver_data:
  
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=${Sa_Password:-password123}
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - sqlserver_data:/var/opt/mssql
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P ${Sa_Password:-password123} -Q 'SELECT 1' || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 3s
  sqlserver.configurator:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    depends_on:
      sqlserver:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: >
      bash -c '
      /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S sqlserver -U sa -P ${Sa_Password:-password123} -d master -i docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;
      echo "All done!";
      '
```

This compose file require you to add init.sql file to init subfolder. Here is an example to create new user:

```
USE [master];
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'newuser')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [newuser] WITH PASSWORD = 'password123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
    ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [newuser];
END
GO
```

Comment: Great work! Worked like a charm! I even tested this docker-compose setup with `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest` image and it also worked!

Answer (score -1):

Docker images for mysql and postgres know about docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory, and how to process it.

For example, for mysql, here is [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/Dockerfile.debian)

It runs script docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh # backwards compat
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

And [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh) runs sql scripts from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory:

```
docker_process_init_files /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
```

Looks like SQL Server docker image does not have processing for docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, you need to study SQL Server Dockerfile or documentation, probably there is some tools to init DB. If there not - you can create your own Docker image, basing on original:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
# implement init db from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: Wait a minute.  So the docker image for MySql contains scripts that can be used by docker compose?  I thought they just packaged the database.  I didnt know you could add stuff.  (mind blown)

Comment: docker-compose used to create container from image (image described in Dockerfile) and run container; and to map directory containing sql scripts into docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory inside container.

Dockerfile contains scripts to install and run sql server and to run sql scripts from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (in case of mysql and postgres); MS SQL Server Dockerfile has different scripts for initialization :)